# Updating an existing Microsoft Band Tile from UWP phone app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I am developing Microsoft Band 2 app using UWP, In that I am trying to access the existing Tile from the app to Update the Tile PageLayout background. 
I have written the below code for creating tile

```
IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
        if (pairedBands.Count() > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
                {
                    // do work after successful connect  
                    // get the current set of tiles  
                    IEnumerable<BandTile> tiles = await bandClient.TileManager.GetTilesAsync();
                    if (tiles.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        int tileCapacity = await bandClient.TileManager.GetRemainingTileCapacityAsync();
                        if (tileCapacity > 0)
                        {
                            // create a new Guid for the tile 
                            Guid tileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
                            // create a new tile with a new Guid 
                            BandTile tile = new BandTile(tileGuid)
                            {
                                // enable badging (the count of unread messages)     
                                // IsBadgingEnabled = true,
                                // set the name     
                                Name = "Torch Tile",
                                TileIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/Electric Bulb.png"),
                                SmallIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/Torchsmaltile.png")
                            };

                            var panel = new FilledPanel
                            {
                                //ElementId = 0,
                                Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 260, 128),
                                BackgroundColor = bandcolor

                            };


                            var layout = new PageLayout(panel);

                            tile.PageLayouts.Add(layout);


                            try
                            {
                                // add the tile to the Band     
                                if (await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile))
                                {
                                    List<PageData> pageDataArray = new List<PageData>();
                                    pageDataArray.Add(new PageData(pageguid, 0, new FilledButtonData(0, Colors.Transparent.ToBandColor())));

                                    await bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(
                                   tileGuid, pageDataArray);

                                }
                            }
                            catch (BandException ex)
                            {
                                // handle a Band connection exception }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            catch (BandException e)
            {
                // handle BandException

            }
        }
```

The following is the code I am trying to Update Tile but not working.

```
IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
            if (pairedBands.Count() > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
                    {

                        // do work after successful connect  
                        // get the current set of tiles  
                        IEnumerable<BandTile> tiles = await bandClient.TileManager.GetTilesAsync();
                        if (tiles.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var tile in tiles)
                            {

                                foreach (var pageLayout in tile.PageLayouts)
                                {
                                    var panel = pageLayout.Root as FilledPanel;
                                    panel.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green.ToBandColor();
                                    pageLayout.Root = panel;

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

After pageLayout.Root = panel; code I am not able to find how to send the changes back to Band Tile.

Can anyone help me how to update the Tile PageLayout background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page layouts themselves are static; once a Tile has been added they cannot be changed (outside of removing and then re-adding the Tile).  The idea is that you instead update the contents (e.g. text) of an instance of a Page (with a given layout).  Section 8.7 of the [Band SDK Documentation](http://developer.microsofthealth.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) describes the content that can be updated within a given Page instance.

For your scenario, the application needs to allow the user to choose a maximum of 5 colors that can be used within your Tile *at any given time*, then define 5 Page layouts that each use one of those colors. (A Tile can have a maximum of 5 Page layouts.) Then you can create 5 page instances, one for each defined layout, to create a Tile that has a Page for each color.  If the user wants to change the mix of colors, then the application will need to remove and then re-add the Tile with a new set of Page layouts.